# IIS7 rewrite module

Tags: asp.net

I got a problem with IIS 7 rewrite module rule

I want it to change any url from below format:

http://www.mysite.com/files/2010/04/background6.jpg

to new url like this:
http://www.mysite.com/="/wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=2010/04/background6.jpg

I added a rule to web.config

```
<rule name="Avatar">
    <match url="^/files/(.*)$" />
     <action type="Rewrite" url="/wp-includes/ms-files.php?file={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

but it does not work, it takes me forever to debug it.

any helps?

thanks you very much

Brian Tran

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ^/. Try

```
<match url="files/(.*)$" />
```